# Start MySQL when Rails server gets started?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When I start my Rails 4.2 app locally I ofter get this error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I then type `mysqld` on my terminal and everything is fine.

Is there a way to start MySQL automatically every time the server gets started?

I am on Mac OS 10.11.5.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you install `MySQL` btw? Also show me the `database.yml` file in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to launch and shutdown several processes together. In your case, you need to list two processes in your `Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec rails server
db: mysqld
```

Then run `foreman start` to start them all. Then Ctrl+C to stop them all.

Answer (score 2):

Have you consider using a bash script to start up your server? So instead of manually running `rails s`, you have a script in which you have your command to run both `mysqld` and then `rails s`, and then just execute this script? Something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqld
rails s
```

On the other hand, if you might want to consider **starting MySQL automatically every time you laptop starts up** so that MySQL is always running in the background, you can [use `launchctl` for this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-launchd.html):

```
sudo launchctl load -w com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go to system preferences, go to the MySql Page, and then select the box that says "Automatically start server on startup". Other than that I dont think there is away to start the MySQL server when the just the rails server starts

[image]

Comment: How did you guess he installed MySql using installer?

Comment: Just an assumption

Comment: Thanks but to be honest I don't remember using this installer thing.